# Mac or PC computer file Bencher in Hebrew and English

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, internet, translation, bentching

I would like to get (for free or for pay) a bencher in Hebrew and English, similar to Artscroll, one side Hebrew and one side English in pdf format that I can open on a Mac or a PC and do some changes. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Ruth Cohen, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you get helpful answers, and that you stick around and find other information of interest. See you around!

Comment: Hi Ruth!  It looks, based on [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97409/mac-or-pc-computer-file-bencher-in-hebrew-and-english#comment323712_97411), like you want to download or buy a bencher file, add a nice border, and print off lots of copies.  Am I correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to achieve. Any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Click here](http://www.aish.com/sh/ht/fn/48970961.html) for a bencher made by Aish HaTorah.

It’s pretty well done, and, while it's a PDF, it's pretty easy to cut and paste into a Word document. The text is provided in Hebrew and English along with transliteration (classic Ashkenazi pronunciation).

Answer (score 5):

Sefaria provides a free Hebrew and English text of benching [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Birkat_Hamazon?lang=bi), following the most common Ashkenazic custom. It's not formatted for printing, but it can be copied and pasted into a custom document.

Chabad has a formatted Hebrew/English bencher PDF [here](https://w3.chabad.org/media/pdf/92404.pdf), following the Chabad custom. As a PDF, it's not readily editable.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Hat-tip to [Salmononius2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5346/salmononius2) for providing this link in a comment.</sup>

Comment: This is amazing Isaac, exactly what I am looking for except I need it in pdf. format or word, all I would do is add a nice border to it, but I must have the file in computer format. I am willing to pay.

Comment: I also was going to mention the Chabad bentcher. Note it's [the same bentcher](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EP-BENT) Kehot sells.